# How to set table row class value dynamically in openui5 / sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

There is a openui5 offical example about [table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/code).

Is there anyway to set class attribute dynamically for table row in the Table.view.xml.

```
<ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
        <ObjectIdentifier
            title="{Name}"
            text="{ProductId}"/>
        <Text
            text="{SupplierName}" />
        <Text
            text="{Width} x {Depth} x {Height} {DimUnit}" />
        <ObjectNumber
            number="{WeightMeasure}"
            unit="{WeightUnit}"
            state="{
                path: 'WeightMeasure',
                formatter: 'sap.m.sample.Table.Formatter.weightState'
            }" />
        <ObjectNumber
                number="{
                    parts:[{path:'Price'},{path:'CurrencyCode'}],
                    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                    formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}
                }"
                unit="{CurrencyCode}" />
    </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
```

Eg. 
row 1

```
<ColumnListItem class="bg-gray">
```

row 2

```
<ColumnListItem class="bg-blue">
```

row 3

```
<ColumnListItem class="bg-green">
```

The following code does not meet the requirements：

```
<ColumnListItem class="{rowStyle}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, 'class' cannot be bound to a property. But there are easy alternatives.

It involves below steps.

1. Create a property (Using CustomData) in the DOM using binding.

   ```
         <ColumnListItem type="Active">
           <customData>
             <core:CustomData key="background" value="{Country}" writeToDom="true" />
           </customData>
           <cells>
               <ObjectIdentifier title="{CustomerID}"/>
               <Text text="{CompanyName}"/> 
               <Text text="{Address}"/> 
               <Text text="{Country}"/> 
           </cells>
       </ColumnListItem>
   ```
2. Use Attribute-Value CSS selectors to select the above
   written DOM and apply color

   ```
   tr[data-background="Mexico"] {
    background-color: #eaa6a6 !Important;
   }
   ```

I have written a blog here.
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/02/binding-based-dynamic-background-colors-for-sap.m.table-rows/

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/jepete/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you very much! child cry milk come!

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatter, function will be like this :

```
setColour : function(Condition){
  if(Condition){
     var cellId = this.getId();
     $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().parent().css("background-color","Blue");
  }
}
```

your column code will be like this :

```
<Input value="{path:'Condition',formatter:'formmater_path.setColour'}" />
```

Comment: hello, do you know, why in the setColour function, "this.getId" is undefined.

Comment: if your condition will be present than this.getId() should not come undefined.

Comment: @vivek Could you explain it better? It doesn't work even if the Condition is not undefined